# Converting List[List[Int]] to Set[Int] in Scala

Tags: scala

Is it possible to convert a List containing inner lists of type `Int` to `Set[Int]` in Scala?

For example, is the following conversion possible:

-> `List(List(0), List(1), List(2))` to `Set(0, 1, 2)`

If yes, can it be explained?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First you need to `flatten` the list then convert it to a set:

```
List(List(0), List(1), List(2)).flatten.toSet
res0: Set[Int] = Set(0, 1, 2)
```

So what does flatten do? When you have multiple nested collections inside of each other it reduces the nesting by one level. This is applicable to anything that's Traversable like for an example `Option`s also.

Comment: Exactly, I came up with the same solution. Thanks very much